# Keeping a CSS Transition at its End State

Tags: html, css, transition

I have a search bar that expands via CSS transitions once it's focussed, but whenever anything outside of it is clicked it resets to its original position. I tried changing the positions and using `animation-fill-mode: forwards`, both not working! (I assumed the later wouldn't work for transitions but I was still told to try it.) Every other similar thread I found on stack only offer these two options...

HTML:

```
<div class="search">
    <input id="searchBar" placeholder="Enter search">
    <button id="searchButton" onclick="getData()">SEARCH</button>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
#searchBar {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #29B6F6;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 15px;
}

#searchBar:focus {
    outline: none;
    color: #29B6F6;
    padding-right: 35%;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tw4fe9aq/) with full code

Comment: When your input loses focus, the padding reverts to normal. Animations can't change that. If you want the state of the search bar to remain permanent after focus, add a class to it with, for instance, `onfocus="this.classList.add('wide')"` and change your CSS style to `#searchBar.wide`. See example here: https://jsfiddle.net/cj9uh2s7/

Comment: You're amazing Will! +1

Comment: And you solved my second problem with the button not activating after the transition! Thank you! +2

Comment: Cool. Glad I could help